# Can't edit an EditText Android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create an AlertDialog dynamically corresponding to the number of Strings in W.englishList. Im adding EditTexts to a grid layout by this way :

```
final Activity act = this;

GridLayout lay = new GridLayout(act);
lay.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);

int row = 1;

for (String i : W.englishList) {
        EditText text = new EditText(act);
        text.setText(i);
        LayoutParams p = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

        p.bottomMargin = 5;
        p.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        p.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
        p.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(tmp);

        text.setLayoutParams(p);
        lay.addView(text);
        row++;
        }
//Some AlertDialog.setContentView(lay);
```

Everything works except that i can't edit the Editexts created, I can focus them, copy them but i can't edit them (the keyboard doesnt show), any ideas ?

Edit: I can copy paste into them.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because allert dialog bloks keyboard.
You can show keyboard always:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or set onTouchListener for each EditText and show keyboard on touch:

```
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

and hide it:

```
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: It seems weird because I have another alert dialog in the app asking for text entries and the keyboard does show. I'm wondering if it's because in the other dialog I made the window with the XML file ?

Comment: May be keyboard sets automatically with xml . I haven't opportunity to test alert dialog with/without xml now, but when i had a similar problem i solved it by this method. However i had only one TextEdit, so it was easier to set onTouchListener.